# Tikz positioning edges not properly

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to model a diagram in Tikz but it doesn't want to position the edges like I want it to. The following code produces the diagram:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{book} %twoside
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{bigblock} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, text width=4em, text centered, node distance=4cm, minimum height=2em]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [bigblock] (host) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [] (title) {Host-OS};
    \node [block, node distance=1cm, below of=title] (emu) {Gast-OS in Emulator};
    \node [block, below of=emu] (xmount) {xmount};
    \node [block, below of=xmount] (bt) {QEMU Blocktreiber};
    \node [block, below of=bt] (curl) {cURL};
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\node [cloud, right of=emu] (user) {Benutzer};
\node [cloud, right of=curl] (ia) {Image Archive};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (emu) -- (xmount);
\path [line] (xmount) -- (bt);
\path [line] (bt) -- (curl);
\path [line] (curl) -- (ia);
\path [line] (user) -- (emu);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

This picture is the result:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Welcome! Your snippet is unfortunately incomplete, missing documentclass, `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. And did you invent the code yourself? If so, why do you put a tikzpicture into a tikzpicture? If not, what is its source?

Comment: The source for this is http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1176/wie-kann-ich-tikz-nodes-verschachteln (in german)
I will update the snippet to a working minimal example...

Comment: Also, what do you want to change? We aren't mind-readers: you only say it doesn't work the way you'd like, but which way is that?

Comment: @cfr I always thought you were brewing a mind-reading potion in your nice cauldron ;-)

Comment: The edges are not placed as discribed in the code, for example the edge from vertice user ("Benutzer") should go to emu ("Gast-OS...")

Comment: @marmot Unfortunately, it isn't finished yet. :(

Comment: @Simon Well, they are. They are placed exactly as described in the code. The 'should go' is your desiderata - not what the code says, else you wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: Just for the records: in your link, the tikzpicture is wrapped in `\pgfinterruptpicture` and `\endpgfinterruptpicture`. This is petty advanced stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should never put a tikzpicture into another tikzpicture (unless you are an expert). Use `fit` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{bigblock} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, text width=4em, text centered, node distance=4cm, minimum height=2em]
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
    \node [] (title) {Host-OS};
    \node [block, node distance=1cm, below of=title] (emu) {Gast-OS in Emulator};
    \node [block, below of=emu] (xmount) {xmount};
    \node [block, below of=xmount] (bt) {QEMU Blocktreiber};
    \node [block, below of=bt] (curl) {cURL};
\node[bigblock,fit=(title) (curl)] (host) {};
\node [cloud, right of=emu] (user) {Benutzer};
\node [cloud, right of=curl] (ia) {Image Archive};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (emu) -- (xmount);
\path [line] (xmount) -- (bt);
\path [line] (bt) -- (curl);
\path [line] (curl) -- (ia);
\path [line] (user) -- (emu);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]